# Is there any way to have eclipse recognise virtual defines per build configuration?

Tags: configuration, eclipse-cdt, c-preprocessor, symbols

I am working on an inherited Borland C/C++ project and a lot of the project's functionality is hidden away behind #ifdefs which rely on defines passed to the compiler.
I have been trying to get eclipse to activate these sections by using per-configuration symbols however when i view the source files, large sections are still greyed out.
Is there any way to tell eclipse about these defines so I can change my build configuration and see which sections of code are being compiled properly?

Answer (score 0):

Is this link to the problem [described in this thread?](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/cdt-dev/msg10808.html)

> > most likely the problem is that the files you are specifying are not found on the include search path.
> >     The difference between `macro-` and `include-files` is that:
> >     - macro files are preprocessed only (i.e. macro definitions are extracted) whereas
> >     - include files are actually parsed (i.e declarations are extracted also).
> >
> > These options should work just like the gcc's `-imacro` and `-include` commandline options.
>
> I see the problem now.
>   I had the indexer turned off for the project.
>   So the file itself was found but the buffer for it was empty because it couldn't locate the file in the index.
>
> After digging around in the code a bit, I found that I could turn on the "Follow unindexed header files when producing the outline view" option in the C/C++ preference page, and then it would parse the macro file correctly.

---

Or is it related to more recent bugs like [bug 197989](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=197989)? (fast indexer may not be accurate when header included multiple times)

Comment: Not quite. The system i have currently set up is an eclipse project containing all the source code, and a makefile with multiple complilers and cross-compilers defined. I have the workspace currently set up with multiple build configurations, which all have custom symbols defined in the project properties.
What i want to do is have eclipse itself define __COMPILER__ to be BCB5 or any of my other compiler strings so that when i look at the source code it recognises blocks protected by #if __COMPILER__ == BCB5 become active when set to the build configuration that defines them.